No se verificó la propiedad del dominio en Google play console
Hola quisiera saber como verificar la propiedad de mi dominio de google play console me sale que no esat verificado y tengo estos errores, ya lo publique en mi dominio pero aun nada



Verificar un dominio es un proceso bien establecido y probado por Google. Si no lo has hecho simplemente debes hacerlo. La mayoría de veces es ingresar a tu hosting desde una url que te da Google.

Pero como se hace?

En serio? En tres meses no lo has resuelto?  El proceso te lo da Google, solo debes seguirlo...

No, no e podido, sigo las instrucciones y nada no me verifica el sitio

Bueno, entonces hay algún lio o con Google o con la propiedad del dominio. Google te dice que mediante un API inicies sesión en tu hosting, cuando el API de Google dice, OK, este fulano si pudo loguearse en el susodicho dominio entonces Google da por valido que el dominio es de tu propiedad. Si ese proceso falla, como repito, o el problema es de Google (que debes hablar con ellos y solo ellos) o es problema de tu hosting e igual debes hablar con los de tu hosting. Nadie externo te puede ayudar a no ser que (por ejemplo) me des las claves y yo intente hacer el proceso
